# Get the sum of all occurences in JSON API (Big Data)

Tags: javascript, json, api

Is there a way to get the sum of all occurrences of an array in JSON API? I'm new to API and Programming and I really want to learn it. Please help me.

Example: https://endcovidph.com/stats-JSON/DOHDataDrop.json

```
[
  {
    "CaseCode": "C100018",
    "Age": 53,
    "AgeGroup": "50 to 54",
    "Sex": "Female",
    "DateRepConf": "2020-05-11",
    "DateDied": "",
    "DateRecover": "",
    "RemovalType": "",
    "DateRepRem": "",
    "Admitted": "",
    "RegionRes": "Region IV-A: CALABARZON",
    "ProvRes": "LAGUNA",
    "CityMunRes": "CITY OF SAN PEDRO",
    "CityMuniPSGC": "PH043425000",
    "HealthStatus": "Mild",
    "Quarantined": "",
    "DateOnset": "",
    "Pregnanttab": "",
    "ValidationStatus": ""
  },
  {
    "CaseCode": "C100119",
    "Age": 31,
    "AgeGroup": "30 to 34",
    "Sex": "Male",
    "DateRepConf": "2020-04-12",
    "DateDied": "",
    "DateRecover": "",
    "RemovalType": "Recovered",
    "DateRepRem": "2020-05-11",
    "Admitted": "Yes",
    "RegionRes": "NCR",
    "ProvRes": "METRO MANILA",
    "CityMunRes": "CITY OF PARAÑAQUE",
    "CityMuniPSGC": "PH137604000",
    "HealthStatus": "Recovered",
    "Quarantined": "No",
    "DateOnset": "2020-03-23",
    "Pregnanttab": "",
    "ValidationStatus": ""
  }
]
```

This API has 327,350 lines of code. Can't insert it all here.

To make it understandable, I need to get the total number of data on the API. For example, In `"ProvRes"` I have `"LAGUNA"` based on the snippet code above. I need to get how many `"LAGUNA"` was written in the API and get the total of it and display it as a number. Maybe using the `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = (count.toLocaleString());` method.

Total number of cases in Laguna: "Total number of Laguna cases here"

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Do you want to take the number of occurrences of the data of "RegionRes",  "ProvRes" and "CityMunRes" ? If those attributes are available in every object, the you can get the no of occurrences of those attributes by just the length of the array. 
Otherwise what you need to do is checking whether those attributes are existing in each object by going through the array and if they're existing should take the count of them.

Comment: What should be the end result, can you be a bit specific about what you are summing?

Comment: My goal is to get the total number of that data. Like for example, in "ProvRes" I have "LAGUNA". I want to get the total of LAGUNA. My target is to get how many LAGUNA was written in the API so that I can display the data in total number in the tracker. The API is now huge and It's now difficult for me to filter the data in Excel to just  see the the number of Laguna word. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think the sample code here demonstrates what you are trying to do.**
The script could be shorter, but I made it verbose for clarity.

If you don't already know, JavaScript **objects** contain 'properties'. Each property has a `key` and a `value`. (The key generally must be a string, but the value can be anything, including another object.)

This script **uses a `collector` object** with 3 properties, 1 for each type of data you are counting. The `key` for each property corresponds to the data type (such as `prs` for `ProvRes`), and the `value` for each property is an object that we can think of as containing many "sub-properties".

As the script loops through the input data, it **will look at the `ProvRes` property of each item** in the input data.
 - If the value is **unfamiliar, it will create a new sub-property** in the `prs` object. The `key` of this sub-property will be the new (unfamiliar) value, and the `value` of the sub-property will be the integer 1 (indicating that we have seen this value 1 time).
 - If the value is **familiar, it will update the corresponding sub-property**, incrementing the value by 1 (because we have now seen this value 1 additional time).

Each time through the loop, the script handles `ProvRes` this way and also handles `CityMunRes` and `CityMuniPSGC`. (Whenever one of these 3 properties is missing from an item in the input data array, JavaScript **will use the value `undefined`**, as can be seen if you run the script in the snippet.)

```js
// Makes demo input data
const dataArray = [
  { "ProvRes": "A", "CityMunRes": "1", "CityMuniPSGC": "#" },
  { "ProvRes": "A", "CityMunRes": "1", "CityMuniPSGC": "#" },
  { "ProvRes": "B", "CityMunRes": "2", "CityMuniPSGC": "$" },
  { "ProvRes": "A", "CityMunRes": "2", "CityMuniPSGC": "$" },
  { "ProvRes": "C", "CityMunRes": "3", "CityMuniPSGC": "%" },
  { "CityMunRes": "4", "CityMuniPSGC": "%" } // No "ProvRes" - treated as `undefined`
];

// Makes a collector object to count occurences of each value
const collector = {
  prs: {},
  cmrs: {},
  cmpsgcs: {}
};

// Loops through all the items in the input data array
for (let item of dataArray){
  
  // Makes a short name for each significant property of the current item
  let pr = item.ProvRes;
  let cmr = item.CityMunRes;
  let cmpsgc = item.CityMuniPSGC;

  // If the current value exists as a key in collector.prs, increments the count
  if(collector.prs[pr]){ collector.prs[pr] += 1; }
  // Otherwise, creates the key and starts the count at 1
  else{ collector.prs[pr] = 1 }

  // Same as above, but for collector.cmrs
  if(collector.cmrs[cmr]){ collector.cmrs[cmr] += 1; }
  else{ collector.cmrs[cmr] = 1 }
  
  // Same as above, but for collector.cmpsgcs
  if(collector.cmpsgcs[cmpsgc]){ collector.cmpsgcs[cmpsgc] += 1; }
  else{ collector.cmpsgcs[cmpsgc] = 1 }
} // This is the end of the for loop

// Displays the finished collection in the browser console
console.log(collector);
```

Comment: This is totally comprehensive! Since you get the data in the const dataArray in your example, how to change it to ajax API call? And how will I use the "A": 3, to display it as document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = (count.toLocaleString()); method? THANK YOU!

Comment: It just depends what your API call sends back to you. If the response is an array, you just set a variable equal to that array, like `const dataArray = myRequest.response` -- or if the response is an object where the array is in a property, it would be more like `const dataArray = myRequest.response.someProperty`.

Comment: How to show stuff on the page depends on your HTML structure, but you could add everything inside an existing `<div id="container"></div>` with code like `const prsKeys = Object.keys(collector.prs); for (let currentkey of prsKeys){ const count = collector.prs[currentKey]; const newDiv = document.createElement("div"); newDiv.textContent = currentKey + " " + count.toLocaleString(); document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newDiv)"; }` Check out MDN (eg https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) to learn more about editing pages.

Comment: Hello again. I don't know how to apply my own logic to your code. But I have the link of my API and I built it. Can you edit and use this link to get the data on your previous code above? By The Way, I am using AJAX to call my API. Thank you so much! Link: https://endcovidph.com/stats-JSON/DataDrop.json

Here's how I get the data from my small API JSON. 

`$.ajax({url: 'https://endcovidph.com/stats-JSON/DataDrop.json',dataType: 'json',success: function (data) {// ADD CODE LOGIC HERE},error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);}});`

Comment: If you look where it says `success: function (data) {//ADD CODE LOGIC HERE}`, whatever you add there will be the code runs when your ajax request has succeeded and returned a JSON-formatted string called `data`. I suggest starting by simply logging `data` to your browser's console (with`console.log(data);`), which you can open with F12.) This way, you can see the returned JSON and decide which part of it you want to keep. This MDN page explains all about working with JSON (including the useful `JSON.parse()` method): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Thank you for helping me Cat! I am now able to understand the mechanism of the code. Stay Home. Stay Safe. God Bless you. :D